# Simple question LaunchMode for SingleInstance

Tags: android, android-manifest, launchmode

I want to ask about android LaunchMode attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Assume that we have A,B,C,D,E and F activity. D and F will be SingleInstance and others will be standart mode. And there is stack as Task1: A->B->C->E and Task2: D in my back-stack. So I want to open my activity F as SingleInstance. What will scenario be?

Comment: Please explain in more detail. What exactly are you asking? If you are using `singleInstance` launch mode then you need to ensure that you set different `taskAffinity` otherwise this won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the launchMode of the Activity F inside `AndroidManifest.xml` as singleInstance.

Try something like:

```
 <activity
    android:name="ActivityF"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I know how to use it, but as I said before, what will the scenario be like?